# Error Initializing Interactive Concole

Tags: python, python-2.7, pydev

A funny behavior started happening on my Win10 64 machine.

PyDev refuses to initialize a "Console for currently active editor" with the following error message:

> Error initializing console. Unexpected error connecting to console.
>   Failed to recive suitable Hello response from pydevconsole. Last msg
>   received: Console already exited with value: 1 while waiting for an
>   answer.
>
> Command Line used:  C:\Anaconda\python.exe -u
>   D:\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_4.5.4.201601292234\pysrc\pydevconsole.py
>   51249 51250 51249 51250
>
> Environment: USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE=... PATH=C:/Program
>   Files/Java/jre1.8.0_71/bin/server;C:/Program
>   Files/Java/jre1.8.0_71/bin;C:/Program 
>   Files/Java/jre1.8.0_71/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program...
>
> ...
>
> PYTHONPATH=D:\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_4.5.4.201601292234\pysrc\pydev_sitecustomize;**D:\CORRECT
>   PATH TO PYTHON PROJECT IS
>   HERE**;C:\Anaconda\DLLs;C:\Anaconda\lib;C:\Anaconda\lib\lib-tk;C:\Anaconda;C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages;C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\Sphinx-1.3.1-py2.7.egg;C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\cryptography-0.9.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg;C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\win32;C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\win32\lib;C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin;C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\setuptools-17.1.1-py2.7.egg
>
> ...

I tried to put some additional commands for `sys.path` or `os.environ` + `os.chdir` into the settings for default commands at initialization, but it never seems to reach that phase and as you can see from the entry in bold the correct path to the python project is there anyway.

Not really sure what else I can provide as info here. It does seem to happen only for some of my projects now.

For other or for new ones it works just fine...

Working with Eclipse Mars 4.5.1 EE and if not obvious from the log PyDev 4.5.4.

I am at a loss... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

pip uninstall traitlets

As is documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29095949/pydev-console-already-ex)

It's worked for me