# 'PyDevTerminalInteractiveShell' object has no attribute 'has_readline'

Tags: python, pycharm

I am using `Pycharm` `2016.1` on `CentOS7` and I am testing "`Show command line afterwards`" and I got this Problem:

```
AttributeError: 'PyDevTerminalInteractiveShell' object has no attribute 'has_readline'
```

---

```
/usr/bin/python3.4 /usr/local/pycharm/helpers/pydev/pydev_run_in_console.py 37196 52554 /root/PycharmProjects/mytf/mytest/test5.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/pycharm/helpers/pydev/pydev_run_in_console.py", line 63, in <module>
  interpreter = InterpreterInterface(host, int(client_port), threading.currentThread())
File "/usr/local/pycharm/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_ipython_console.py", line 26, in __init__
  self.interpreter = get_pydev_frontend(host, client_port, show_banner=show_banner)
File "/usr/local/pycharm/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_ipython_console_011.py", line 473, in get_pydev_frontend
  _PyDevFrontEndContainer._instance = _PyDevFrontEnd(show_banner=show_banner)
File "/usr/local/pycharm/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_ipython_console_011.py", line 303, in __init__
  self.ipython = PyDevTerminalInteractiveShell.instance()
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/traitlets/config/configurable.py", line 412, in instance
  inst = cls(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/terminal/interactiveshell.py", line 359, in __init__
  super(TerminalInteractiveShell, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 487, in __init__
  self.init_completer()
File "/usr/local/pycharm/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_ipython_console_011.py", line 222, in init_completer
  self.Completer = self._new_completer_200()
File "/usr/local/pycharm/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_ipython_console_011.py", line 194, in _new_completer_200
  use_readline=self.has_readline,
AttributeError: 'PyDevTerminalInteractiveShell' object has no attribute 'has_readline'
```

Comment: It was known issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-20013 which is fixed in PyCharm 2016.2.

Answer (score 49):

This PyCharm issue occurs because of changes the the `iPython` api with `iPython` version 5. Until Jetbrains fix this, reverting to an earlier version of `iPython` (version 4) will correct this. As @chenfei has discovered, this can be done through `pip`:

```
$ pip uninstall ipython
$ pip install ipython==4.2.0
```

**Edit**

And if you can't wait that long, Jetbrains have released a patch

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-20013#comment=27-1512407

**Final Edit**

This issue has been fixed in PyCharm 2016.2

Answer (score 11):

I solved my problem via installing ipython version 4.2:

```
pip uninstall ipython
pip install ipython==4.2.0
```

Answer (score 6):

The way I managed to solve this problem **without downgrading `iPython`** was:

**1** - Download the following patch:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/_persistent/pycharm_ipython5_fix.patch?file=74-327779&c=true

**2** - Inside `PyCharm`, create a new project located on:

```
<PyCharm installation folder>/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/
```

`Pycharm` will prompt you to import the files on that folder, **accept**.

**3** - Click on <kbd>VCS</kbd> and choose <kbd>Apply Patch</kbd>

**4** - Choose the file you've downloaded on **step 1**.

**5** - The <kbd>Apply Patch</kbd> window will open, click <kbd>OK</kbd>

**6** - Restart `PyCharm`

The Python Console should be now working inside `PyCharm`

---

PS: You can delete the project folder (.idea) you've created on **Step 2**

Answer (score 1):

It's solved in Pycharm 2016.2. See here:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207207329-ipython-5-not-supported-by-Pycharm-s-python-console-